# Filter a JavaScript array containing an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to filter a table based on the user's input (search). This search string sends a teamId to the getFilteredPlayers function and I would like to return a list of players that are linked to that teamId. See an example of a player in the players array below;

[image]

See getFilteredPlayers function below, it is not returning anything currently. Please recommend some changes please

```
let getFilteredPlayers = (players, search) => {
            if (search && search.length > 0) {
                return players.filter((x) => {
                    return search.any((y) => x.playersTeams == y);
                });
            }
            return players;
        };
```

Comment: `players.filter(p => p.playersTeams.some(t => t.teamId === search))`

Comment: thanks for this, where do i put it?

Comment: inside the `if` block. Replace `players.filter(...)` with the above filter code

Comment: let getFilteredPlayers = (players, search) => {
        if (search && search.length > 0) {
            return players.filter(p => p.playersTeams.some(t => t.teamId === search))
        };
        return players;
    };

it is not working like this

Comment: What is the value in `search`? This works only if `search` has the entire `teamId` string. You have mentioned that *"This search string sends a teamId*"

Comment: Search is an array that contains teamId(s) ; 
['08da89a7-bc69-489e-8643-0a8290d2c6bf']

Comment: Then you need something like this: `players.filter(p => p.playersTeams.some(t => search.includes(t.teamId) ))`